# jQuery validation not firing when using raw JavaScript submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have jQuery validation on my form. When I click submit button, 'save' function is called:

```
function save(){
    var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
    form.submit(); // <- jquery validation is not called
    $(form).submit() // <- jquery validation works
}
```

Why form.submit() is not validating my form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [native `submit` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.submit) ([W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-form-element.html#dom-form-submit)) will submit the form, and nothing else. It does not fire a cancelable `submit` event (see [concept of form submit](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/form-submission.html#concept-form-submit)).

jQuery's [`submit` method](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) is an alias for `.trigger("submit")`, but "*in addition, the default submit action on the form will be fired* [invoked]*, so the form will be submitted.*"

Your validation will listen for those submit events, which don't happen when using the native submit method.

Comment: When I'm calling native onclick method, jQuery click event is firing, it's right? When I'm calling native submit method, jQuery submit is NOT fired. That's strange, because there is native event 'onsubmit'