# $form.submit(function(){......}); is not working

Tags: php, html, jquery

i created a Registrtion form and i used ajax to validate the form.And my problem is $form.submit(function(){.....}); is not working.I will explain the problem.Below shown is the code for ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var $form=$('#myform');
        //debugger;
        $form.submit(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'registrationvalidation.php',
                data:$("#myform").serialize(),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    if(data=="ok")
                        {
                           return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert(data);
                            return false;
                        }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and submit is replaced by live function ,it is working as required.This is the working code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        //var $form=$('#myform');

        //debugger;
        //$form.submit(function()
        $("#submit").live('click',function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'registrationvalidation.php',
                data:$("#myform").serialize(),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    if(data=="ok")
                        {
                           return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert(data);
                            return false;
                        }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But in my program i want to use submit function because i am posting some data from html form to another page after submit.And when i am executing the same code(1st code) using chrome developer tools it is working properly.Any one know the solution..
Html form

```
<form id="myform" action="insert.php" method="post" >
        <h1>Personal Information</h1>
        <fieldset id="personal">
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME" autofocus><br>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME"><br>
            <input id="gender" name="gender" type="text" placeholder="GENDER" ><br>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL"><br>
            <input id="date" name="date" type="date" placeholder="JOINING DATE" ><br>
            <input id="designation" name="designation" type="text" placeholder="DESIGNATION"><br>
        </fieldset>
        <h1>Login Info</h1>
        <fieldset id="logininfo">
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="USER NAME" ><br>
            <input id="password1" name="password1" type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" ><br>
            <input id="password2" name="password2" type="password" placeholder="CONFORM PASSWORD" ><br>
        </fieldset>
        <h1>Permissions</h1>
        <fieldset id="permission" align="center">
            View&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<input id = "VIEW" name="view" type = "checkbox" value = "view" /> <br>
            Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<input id = "EDIT"name="edit" type = "checkbox" value = "edit" /> <br>
            Delete&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<input id = "DELETE"name="delete" type = "checkbox" value = "delete" /> <br>
            Permission&nbsp;&nbsp;:<input id = "PERMISSION" name="permission"type = "checkbox" value = "perms" /> <br>
            Add User&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<input id = "ADD" name="add" type = "checkbox" value = "add" /> <br>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
            <!--<input type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />this is for submit function-->
            <div id="idd"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what the goal of `return true|false` in ajax success?

Comment: True is for submitting the form ,flase is for not

Comment: that's not possible in asynchronous call. Your `return false` is executed after the submit form

Comment: it's ok..but why form.submit(function(){..}); is not working

Answer (score 1):

You should cancel the form submission and manually submit it when the AJAX succeeds:

```
var oForm = $('#myform');
oForm.submit(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'registrationvalidation.php',
        data: oForm.serialize(),
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            if(data=="ok")
            {
                oForm[0].submit();
            }
            else
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Having "return false" in the AJAX callback is meaningless, it won't affect the form submission whatsoever.

Comment: this does not cause a submit loop?

Comment: @chumkiu good call! Changed the code to submit the native form element, it won't trigger the jQuery event this way. ([test](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcMEj/))

Comment: it works, but I don't understand why. The submit event should works also with native trigger. Have you some referer to doc for this?

Comment: @chumkiu there is excellent explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12821643/447356). :)

Comment: +1 Thank you :-) Just a question: it's safe crossbrowser? (IE?)

Comment: @chumkiu yes, submit event is pretty much in the very core of JavaScript.