# Binding event to programmatical form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

There is a form and a button.

```
<a href="javascript:myFunc();">submit</a> 
<script>
function myFunc()  
{  
   //some actions here  
   var myForm = document.getElementById(formId);
   myForm.submit();  
}  
</script>
```

Now I want to bind another function to submit event of the form without modifying the first part:

```
<script>  
    $('formSelector').on('submit', function(){
         alert(123);
    });
</script>
```

The above function is not executed. The form is submitted by `myFunc()`
Is there a way to `alert(123)` before form submit?

UPD: myFunc(). sorry, my mistake

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/9w3z5/.

Comment: @FelixKling as undefined mentioned, his selector is wrong.

Comment: @Johan: Then how come the form gets submitted? I assume `formSelector` is just a placeholder in this example.

Comment: Afaik this only fails when you are submitting the form with the native method: `domElement.submit()`. In contrast, `$jQueryElement.submit()` *does* fire the event.

Comment: @FelixKling maybe smth. else is wrong on the page( Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you forget to use `$(document).ready`? You can only bind the event handler to the element when it exists.

Comment: @Bergi !!!! 100% right! I haven't noticed "var myForm = document.getElementById(form_id);" changing the question. please write it as an answer

Comment: You should be modifying the first part of your code because its bad. Hacking around bad code is just adding bad code to bad code. Please consider not writing bad code.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I know. but the website is too big and there are too many things connected. You know, in big projects one always wants to rewrite everything, but it is not my decision(

Comment: @Ivil, thats not an excuse for writing bad code, especially in a big project. If you have a big project full of bad code, that is the first thing you need to address, because adding more bad code to the bad code will make things even worse for you in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery validation not firing when using raw JavaScript submit function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821600/jquery-validation-not-firing-when-using-raw-javascript-submit-function)

Comment: @lvil: Explaining the reason is not an answer to "*how to catch it without changing the code*" :-) There are several ways to intercept the method calls without changing the first part, but they're hacky. If you want to submit your form so that other listeners are called, you just should trigger them - change the first part.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in this cases, is to rise custom event, something like that

```
 function myFunc()  
{  
   //some actions here  
   $('formSelector').submit().trigger('customSubmitEvent');  
}
```

then listening to the same event:

```
<script>  
    $('formSelector').on('customSubmitEvent', function(){
        alert(123);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And how/where are you submitting the form?

Comment: Why would this be considered a best practice? Also, you are never submitting the form in the code you provided.

Comment: When registering more than 1 handler to submit event, you can't guarantee which handler will execute first, like validation for say.

Comment: Now you are submitting the form before you are triggering the custom event. That's exactly the opposite of what the OP wants to do. And FYI, as long as you bind the handlers with jQuery, the order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try listening on the "onclick" event of the a element. However, it itsn't a good practice to use the href attr to call for arbitrary functions.

```
<a id="forsubmitter" href="#">submit</a> 
<script>
jQuery(document).on('click','#formsubmitter',function() {
   if (myFunc()) {
        alert('conditions met, submitting');
        $('formSelector').submit();  
    } else {
        alert('conditions not met, but submitting anyway!');
        $('formSelector').submit();  
    }
});
function myFunc()      {  
    if (some conditions are met) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that you are assigning submit handler before the DOM is ready and selector does not match any form. Try wrapping event handler with DOM ready function:

```
$(function() {
    $('formSelector').on('submit', function(){
        alert(123);
    });
});
```